# pysvn request for SVN ROOT when is requesting a branch

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

PROBLEM: When updating a branch(http://svn.exemple.com/root/workspace/branch) with pysvn.Client, it requests for svn root(http://svn.exemple.com/root), and receives merited ClientError ( 403 Forbidden ).

It occurred on linux-2.6(redhat-5.6-Final), when I tested on Windows 7, the code worked well.

CODE like this:

```
def _initClient(self):
    self._client = pysvn.Client()
    self._client.exception_style = 1
    self._client.set_default_username(self.configObj.SVN_USER)
    self._client.set_default_password(self.configObj.SVN_PASSWD)
    try:
        self.cur_revision_number = self._client.info(self._workcopy)["revision"].number
    except pysvn.ClientError:
        self.cur_revision_number = self._client.checkout(self.configObj.SVN_SERVER,self._workcopy).number

def update(self, pathname=None, **kwargs):
    '''
    Update workcopy

    Extra kwargs are:
        recurse=True,
        revision=version("head"),
        ignore_externals=False,
        depth=depth
    '''

    if not pathname:
        path = self._workcopy
    elif os.path.isabs(pathname):
        path = pathname
        if self._workcopy not in path:
            raise ValueError("Unkown workcopy \"%s\"" % pathname)
    else:
        path = os.path.join(self._workcopy, pathname)

    self.cur_revision_number = self._client.update(
            path, **kwargs
        )[-1].number
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the file leads to this problem:
    media/portal/images/favicon.ico
with
    svn version: 1.6.11
    pysvn version: 1.7.6

It may be redirect to /favicon.ico by Apache.